# Selenium Python XPath, how to extract only the text in the DIV and not the text in internal spans

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="discount-promo" style="" xpath="1">-50%<span class="text">2a Unidad</span></div>
```

I extract OK text from span:

```
s = root.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="discount-promo"]//span[@class="text"]')
s.text
'2a Unidad'
```

but for text inside div:

```
d = root.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="discount-promo"]')
d.text
'-50%\n2a Unidad'
```

for this case I need to extract exactly "-50%", or whatever other value it takes, without having to use regex, just by XPath.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short code should give you the parent element text only:

```
parent_element = root.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="discount-promo"]')
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', parent_element).strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
.//div[@class="discount-promo"]/text()[1]
```

Or, in a whole:

```
d = root.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="discount-promo"]/text()[1]')
```

The output should be as expected.

Comment: Hi, it throws me the following error:    WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null